# restricting a user's direct access to JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I have trouble with restricting user access to some pages. I send an ajax request to servlet. In ajax success I want to redirect a page to another page based on condition. But i set a servlet constraint in web xml, so redirection results in error with 403 code. response.sendredirect also does't work as it is an ajax request.

Any ideas? please, help me to do this redirection with relevant restrictions.

Comment: Uh, shouldn't the user just login first? I really don't understand the concrete problem. `response.sendRedirect()` would surely also not have worked if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: the concrete problem is: I want to redirect to a page in javascript which has a constraint (in web.xml)....

<security-constraint>
      <display-name>Restrict pages</display-name>

      <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>name</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint/>
   </security-constraint>

Error with 403 occurs when I write window.locaation = pageIwantToGo.jsp...

Comment: So you want to make an AJAX request to your server, and based on the response, perform a redirect to another page or not. Do I get this right?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy solution for your problem.
That's to put the jsp files(which you don't want to be accessed by users directly) inside WEB-INF folder. The reason? Well,everything inside WEB-INF folder is by default private members of the whole application. That means that, these files can only be accessed by programs i.e. servlets.
So if any user try to directly access the jsp pages, he/she will get "Http 404" error.
In this way you may restrict user access to specific files.